# Does the DataContractSerializer call property getters/setters?

Tags: .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

I know that on deserialization the DataContractSerializer does not call the constructor.  Does it also bypass a public or private property's setter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it out -- The property accessors are not bypassed regardless of visibility (public, private, etc).